# Issue replacing content with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm working with a CMS spanish website, and I'm trying to replace the months to spanish.

This is how it looks like with the date function **date("F j, Y, g:i a")**:

```
August 24, 2011, 1:47 pm
```

Now I want it to look like this:

```
Agosto 24, 2011, 1:47 pm
```

Using an example from the [Php Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) I made this:

```
$p['time'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
        $time_english = $p['time'];
        $search  = $time_english('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
        $replace = $times_spanish('Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
        $subject ='August';
        str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

The following error appears:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function August 24, 2011, 3:50 pm() in
    $search  = $time_english('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
```

Comment: You are calling $time_english and $time_spanish as functions, it should be array().

Answer (score 2):

It would be far easier to just use [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php). All you have to do is set a `locale` and you can output in your desired language.

Example:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');    // I think it´s es_ES
$my_time = strftime("%B %e, %G, %I:%M %P");    // something like that...
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @Gabriel I have added an example.

Comment: I'm placing setlocale(LC_TIME, "es_ES"); before the date functions and it's not working

Comment: @Gabriel I think it depends on the installed locales on the server, perhaps it´s something like: `setlocale (LC_TIME, "es_ES.ISO8859-1");`

Comment: @Gabriel In linux you can check which locales are installed from the command line: `$ locale -a`

Comment: Strange, setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES'); didn't work either with strtime time example you gave me...

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean

```
    $search  = array('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    $replace = array('Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
```

instead of

```
    $search  = $time_english('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
    $replace = $times_spanish('Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
```

---

As a point of interest, the reason your error says it's trying to call a function named `August 24, 2011, 3:50 pm()` is because of the apparent variable function name `$time_english()`. It's returning the value of `$time_english` then trying to run that as a function.

---

Here's the whole thing:

```
$p['time'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$time_english = $p['time'];
$search  = array('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$replace = array('Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
$time_spanish = str_replace($search, $replace, $time_english);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably correct one

```
$p['time'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

$search  = array('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$replace = array('Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to save this into the variable time, how can I achieve this?

`  $p['time'] = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
  $time = $p['time'];
  $search  = array('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
  $subject ='August';
  $replace = array('Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre');
  str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);`

Comment: before str_replace add `$time =`

Comment: It's only returning 'Agosto', the day and hour are missing :(